# querySelector not selecting class

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron App and Within my index.html file, I import a number of html files in the `<head>` like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="settings.html">
<link rel="import" href="dashboard.html">
<link rel="import" href="locker.html">
```

For now, each file is the same, but with a different header, and follows the same template:

```
<template class="section-template">
  <section id="locker" class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>Locker</h3>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

In my JavaScript I have the following function that triggers on page load:

```
console.log(`Importing all to DOM`);
const links = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]')

Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link){
  var content = link.import;
  var el = content.querySelector('.section-template');
  console.log(el);
})
```

This is selecting all the imported files, calling them and then it should be selecting the whole file based on the section-template class.

For some reason, el is null and I cannot figure out why.  Logging out the `content` shows this.  Not sure why the content is appearing in the `<head>`, though I think this is part of the issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxX6.jpg

I've copied the HTML of the locker.html file into JSFiddle, and ran the JavaScript on document which works fine.

A little confused as to why this isn't working.

Update:  Example to how this should work here under imports
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: What browser are you testing this in; have you checked to make sure it supports this …? http://caniuse.com/#search=import

Comment: @CBroe Its how you access the content of an import.  Link is the array element, link.import saves the html of that file to ```content```  Its used in Electron, so the latest version of Chromium I believe

Comment: Well have you logged `content` to the console and checked what that actually contains/is …?

Comment: Yes, it contains the html of each file.  They all start with #document, though I dont think thats relevant. http://imgur.com/a/612c8

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use f.e. a normal `div` instead of `template` …?

Comment: To me, `link.import` doesn't look correct.

Comment: @Ematipico how so? It seems to read correctly here too https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/